# Problems when configuring spec folder in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm practising TDD stuff in Rails4 with rspec and intend to create several folders by command such as `factories`, `model`, `requests`, `controller`. So I add such line into `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g| 
  g.test_framework :rspec, 
    :model_specs => true, 
    :view_specs => false, 
    :helper_specs => false, 
    :routing_specs => false, 
    :controller_specs => true, 
    :request_specs => true 
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories" 
end
```

However. when i run `rails g rspec:install` in command line. System return Error:

```
/home/rayvonmice/workspace/kulu/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /home/rayvonmice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
    from /home/rayvonmice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

So i don't quite get what's wrong with the `config/application.rb` file. Does that mean i can only generate those folders manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're calling `config` outside of where it's defined.

Try moving your code into the block that starts with:

```
module Kulu
  class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.generators do |g| 
    g.test_framework :rspec, 
      :model_specs => true, 
      :view_specs => false, 
      :helper_specs => false, 
      :routing_specs => false, 
      :controller_specs => true, 
      :request_specs => true 
    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories" 
  end
  ...
end
```